# still having cors issue after adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in apache2

Tags: apache2

I added following lines to my apache2.conf file for solving the cors issue.

```
<Directory /var/www/html/rcycLatest2/RCYC/presentation/angular/rcyc>  
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:4200" 
</Directory>
```

but it still showing following error

```
Failed to load http://localhost/angular5/lesson2.pdf: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I also tried with '*' in place of Access-Control-Allow-Origin url,but it still showing same error.I already spend one day in this issue,can someone  please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: did you try to restart apache afterwards?, make sure the configuration and the path to the project is correct, also did you try to access it in Incognito Mode from chrome or Private Window in firefox? useful info: https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

Comment: I follwed this link  [https://poanchen.github.io/blog/2016/11/20/how-to-enable-cross-origin-resource-sharing-on-an-apache-server] to enable cors,and done everything as per the guidelines provided in that page.

Comment: tried to access it with in incognito mode but,still showing same error.

Comment: link isn't working, apache has multiple config files, make sure you added that in the correct file

Comment: i added it in apache2.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

### I can suggest 2 options:

#### option 1:

If your backend server is node (or if you just started a project and don't mind to a rapid install of [node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)):

I would recommend you use [Express.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express), this would be the quickest setup for a REST API on your local and you will see how easily I set cors right:

```
let express = require('express');
let cors = require('cors');//<= CORS package install this with "npm i cors" in your console

let app = express();


 app.use(cors()); //<== this solves your cors issue

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    console.log('ready and listening on port 3000');
    res.send('hello there, cors issue solved!);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

once you run this `index.js`, your Node server would be located at `http://localhost:3000`

#### options 2:

Another route to take, and TBH a much faster one, would be to use the [Moesif Origin Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc), suffice to say that you would need chrome for this.

Godspeed.